# How could i create a Jtable with all files from directory and subdirectory on java

Tags: java, file

I have this code, so my problem is that in a jtable i should introduce all the files have been found, in the jtable the columns are the first name of file, second column the rute or direction and third one the date of the file.
I need to create arraylist in java where i save all the files than have been found

this the code:

```
    for(int i =0; i < diret.length;i++){ 
        for(int j =0; j < diret.length;j++){
            File f = new File(dire.getAbsolutePath(),diret[j]);
           if(f.isDirectory()){
               String nombreSub[] = f.list();
               tamanio = nombreSub.length;
               for(int z =0; z < nombreSub.length;z++){
                   n1.add(nombreSub[z]);
                   n2.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                   n3.add(date.format(f.lastModified()));
               }
           }
        }

    }


    for( int i =0; i < tamanio+diret.length;i++){
        documento nFile = new documento((String)n1.get(i),(String)n2.get(i),(String)n3.get(i));

        doc.add(nFile);
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question title? In the text you explain (correctly) that for a JTable you want a List. However, in the question title, you say you want a String, which is something else, and a String is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A very rudimentary solution to what you're asking is the following. This will effectively create a new `JTable` listing all the files from top level to subdirectories given a path.

```
public class FileTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var frame = new JFrame();
        var table = new JTable(new FileTestModel(getFiles("D:\\test")));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
    }

    private static List<FileContent> getFiles(String directory) {
        List<FileContent> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try (var pathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get(directory))) {
            list = pathStream
              .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
              .map(Path::toFile)
              .map(file -> new FileContent(file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath(), new Date(file.lastModified())))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("An error has occurred:: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static final class FileTestModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final String[] COLUMNS = { "File Name", "Root Path", "File Date" };

        private final List<FileContent> contents;

        FileTestModel(List<FileContent> contents) {
            this.contents = contents;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() { return contents.size(); }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() { return COLUMNS.length; }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMNS[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return contents.get(rowIndex).getFileName();
            case 1:
                return contents.get(rowIndex).getRootPath();
            case 2:
                return contents.get(rowIndex).getFileDate();
        }
        return null;
    }

    }

    private static final class FileContent {

        private final String fileName;
        String getFileName() { return fileName; }

        private final String rootPath;
        String getRootPath() { return rootPath; }

        private final Date fileDate;
        Date getFileDate() { return fileDate; }

        FileContent(String fileName, String rootPath, Date fileDate) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.rootPath = rootPath;
            this.fileDate = fileDate;
        }

    }

}
```

With this you walk a given directory retrieving all regular files mapping them to a `File` object and then mapping them to an intermediate `FileContent` object. When the retrieval action gets done, then the results are shown using a very simple `JTable`.

You can use this example to guide you. Ideally, I would have the file retrieval action run on a separate thread in order to avoid lagging when listing a big directory (since this is a blocking action) and I would have had a loader be shown in the jtable table but for the purposes of this example this would do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the issue you have here is that the number of files that have been found may be more than:

```
tamanio+diret.length
```

How I would approach this issue is to have a counter which I set to 0 at the start of this code, then incremented by one within the:

```
if(f.isDirectory())
```

condition.
Hope this helps